# How to alter number of columns [with awk] only if a string is in the 1st column of the line while printing changed line and whole text

Tags: bash, awk, replace

I want to replace the number of columns, only use 1st and last one for each line containing a `>`.

But then I want to print the whole file again, with the changed lines like this.

```
>TRF [name1]  
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTGGA 
ATGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGC
```

I have tried with this code but it only returns the changed lines. Thanks.

```
awk '$1 ~ />/ { print $1" "$NF}' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk '$1 ~ />/ { $0 = $1 " " $NF} 1' file
```

Default action `1` in the end will print all lines from input.